# SSIS Import excel sheet error

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Hi  I am tring to import data from excel to sql 2005 .working fine in VS2005,but not working while running from cmd using dtexec.
error description as follows
"Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult
: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the
 object .
Can anyone help how to resolve this issue

Comment: Double check the path to the excel file you are reading and the name och the cheet in the file you are actually reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly be a permissions error.  If the account that is running the package doesn't have sufficient rights on the target folder or object, then this kind of error could be raised by SSIS.  You wouldn't see this error in BIDS if your personal account has sufficient rights to access the file location.

Do you receive this error when the package is executed via a SQL Server Agent job?  Do you receive this error when logged into the server that runs the code using the credentials of the SQL Server Agent?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see you you have the property 'Set DelayValidation' = false

([Microsoft Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/3390b595-ae59-41b2-afa0-e7f53464e65a?prof=required))

If it still does not work, check to see if you have the package sensible information, encrypted to the user package creator (package properties), this inhibits another user to run the package (safety issues).

Hope it helps,

Bruno